# Calculate the sum of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n^2+n)3^{n-1}}{4^n} $$

I tried to build numerator and denominator in desmos, and apparently numerator goes to infinity faster than denominator, so the series should be divergent, isn't it?

Comment: Just use the ratio test...the polynomial terms don't matter and the ratio of successive terms approaches $\frac 34$.  But were you interested in convergence or the numerical value of the sum?

Comment: Numerical value

Comment: Well, you have to look at closed formulas for things like $\sum n\,r^n$ and $\sum n^2\,r^n$.  Hint:  start with $\sum r^n=\frac 1{1-r}$.  Differentiate in $r$ to get $\sum nr^{n-1}=\frac 1{(1-r)^2}\implies \sum n\,r^n=\frac r{(1-r)^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n^2+n)3^{n-1}}{4^n}&=\frac14\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}\bigg|_{x=3/4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1}\\&=\frac14\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}\bigg|_{x=3/4}\frac x{1-x}\\&=\frac1{2(1-x)^3}\bigg|_{x=3/4}\\&=\frac1{2(1-3/4)^3}\\&=\boxed{32}\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you please tell me what happened with (n^2 +n), can't figure it out.

Comment: Take the derivative of $x^{n+1}$ twice to see where it went.

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac{(n^2+n)3^{n-1}}{4^n}=\dfrac13\left(n(n-1)x^n+2nx^n\right)$$ where $x=\dfrac34$

Now for $|x|<1,\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\dfrac1{1-x}$

Differentiate wrt $x$ and multiply by $x$

Again,  differentiate

Comment: Could you please explain a couple of moments. How can I differentiate wrt x, when it's not a functional series and x is a constant value? As far as I get it, I should place 1/(1-x) out of sum symbol and differentiate what's left?

Comment: @JackNickolson, Forget $$\dfrac34$$ for the time being and reach the sum s $$n(n-1)x^n+2nx^n$$   which holds true for $|x|<1$  Finally set $x=\dfrac34$